# How to pass variables to a Mapper using Python's Hadoopy library?

Tags: python, mapreduce, hadoopy

When running a MapReduce job on Python based on the Hadoopy library, how to pass variables (in addition to the key and value pair) to a mapper?

I couldn't find any examples or documents clarifying this.  Could someone show me an example or point out references?  Thanks!